# Is it more efficient to delete rows or re-create a table on Snowflake

Tags: sql, optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-delete

I have a table with 600M rows, and I want to delete a subset of those rows with ids coming from another table.

Will it be more efficient to delete the rows or re-create the table?

(Based on a discussion on the dbt Slack)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. Sometimes `DELETE` is faster, sometimes `CREATE OR REPLACE table` is the best option.

The mental model we have to use is that all the data in a table lives in multiple Snowflake "micro-partitions". If my `DELETE` is going to touch only one of those micro-partitions - either because I'm deleting only one row, or because all the rows I'm deleting are well clustered into a single micro-partition - then `DELETE` is faster.

But if my `DELETE` is going to touch multiple micro-partitions of a table - I'd rather rebuild the whole table again.

For example, let's setup a clone of TPC-H-SF100:

```sql
create or replace table lineitem_100
as
select *
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf100.lineitem
order by l_shipdate
;

select count(*)
from lineitem_100
-- 600,037,902
;

create table lineitem_100b
clone lineitem_100;

create table lineitem_100c
clone lineitem_100;
```

Deleting a random set of rows takes 25s:

```
use warehouse fh_3xl
;
delete from lineitem_100b
where l_orderkey in (
    select o_orderkey
    from orders_100
    where o_totalprice between 50000 and 120000
)
-- 25s
```

But re-creating the table without those rows takes half the time instead:

```
insert overwrite into lineitem_100c
select *
from lineitem_100
where l_orderkey not in (
    select o_orderkey
    from orders_100
    where o_totalprice between 50000 and 120000
)
order by l_shipdate
-- 13s
```

You can see that when re-creating the table I'm also taking care of clustering it well with the `order by`.

It's also interesting to note that I did a `insert overwrite` instead of `create or replace table` - this way we get to keep all the policies and other metadata we could have applied to the table.

Delete:

[image]

Recreate:

[image]

Comment: since we dont know number of rows in a  micro partitions and we dont know how the data is distributed, its possible all deleted rows may exist in different partitions. So, we can delete if its 5-10% of whole table, else recreate is the better option. Quick R&D like @Felipe did is best.

Comment: Also if you have cluster on, the create will cost less. Because the delete will write the partitons unsorted, and then cluster will rewrite then all. Thus do a create with sort (by clustering keys) will have a total cost and general time to complete faster, than delete & auto-clustering.